# Are my cache references and hits wrong because of my BufferedReader?

Tags: java, caching, memory, data-structures, bufferedreader

I am having an issue with the correct amount of cache hits and misses in my implementation for my data structures course.

I am using a buffered reader as follows in order to read every line of an encyclopedia:

```
            try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[2]))){
                String line;
                
                while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                    String[] keys = line.split(" ");
                    if(line.trim().length()>0){
                        for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
                            list.getObject(keys[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch
```

Within my Encyclopedia.txt file, there are 1,347,451 words, which means that my number of references should be just about that, however I am over by 95,699.

The number of hits I am supposed to have for this file should be 837,461, given a cache size of 1000, but again I am over by 95,578.

Below is my code where I increment the number of references(nr1) and the number of hits(nh1):

```
public T getObject(T key){
        if(fCache.size()==0){
            //if it is the first element being added
            fCache.add(key);
        }else{
            int target=0;
            if((target=fCache.indexOf(key))!=(-1)){
                //first cache contains key
                fCache.remove(target);
                fCache.add(key);
                nh1++;
            }else{
                //first cache does not contain key
                if(fCache.size()>=fSize){
                    //too big
                    fCache.remove(0);
                    fCache.add(key);
                }else if(fCache.size()<fSize){
                    fCache.add(key);
                }
            }
        }
    nr1++;
}
```

The above snippet is the only place where nr1 and nh1 are incremented, so I am assuming that with larger files, BufferedReader is calling getObject() too many times, but I do not understand why, as it works fine on smaller files.

EDIT:

expected output is:

```
The number of 1st-level references: 1347451
 10 The number of 1st-level cache hits: 837461
 11 The 1st-level cache hit ratio             : 0.6215149938661962
```

and my output is:

```
The number of 1st-level references: 1443150
The number of 1st-level cache hits: 933039
The number of 1st-level cache hit ratio : 0.6465294667913938
```

Comment: *"off by nearly 96,000"* High or low?

Comment: off by nearly 96,000 high.

Comment: `else if(fCache.size()>0)` --- Can `size()` be negative? Of course not, so why have an `if` there, when `else` is enough?

Comment: You have `nr1++;` in 3 places, but as far as I can see, there is no path thru the code that doesn't reach exactly 1 of them, so why not just have a single `nr1++;` at the end of the method?

Comment: What is the value of `nr1` and `nh1` at the end of the run? What is the size of `fCache`? Have you checked if `key` is ever an empty string? You're asking for help, so please provide exact information, not just "off by *nearly* 96,000". And how do you know there are 1,347,451 words in the file?

Comment: My exact values have been updated in my edit, as well as desired output vs. actual. I used wc to count the number of words in the file, and have also been given desired output files from my instructor.

Comment: *Best guess:* There are about 96000 "words" that are not words, e.g. are empty strings or just symbols, like `""`, `"-"`, `"*"`, ... --- Try looking at the content of the cache, i.e. do some **research** into what extraneous values might have been processed by your code..